# building a angular view based on ajax response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to get started with Angular(1), I have a layout where the nav needs to change based on the type of user that is logged in, when the page loads I send a request to the API to the user object (this I will share with the other controllers on the page).

This is my controller so far,

```
app.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, UserService, $rootScope){
        $scope.loading = true;

        if($scope.loading) {
            $scope.doInitialisation
        }

        $scope.isSuper = function() {
            if($scope.user.isSuper == 1) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        UserService.authenticatedUser()
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.loading = false;
                $rootScope.user = response.message;
            }, function(error) {
                $scope.hasError = true;
                $scope.errors = error.message;
            });
    });
```

In my template I doing something like to try and show a UL based on the user type,

```
<ul ng-if="isSuper()" ng-include="dashboard/nav/super.html"id="sidebar-menu" class="sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">

</ul><!-- #sidebar-menu -->
```

I get the following error,

> Cannot read property 'isSuper' of undefined

I assume it is because isSuper() is being fired before my ajax has loaded, is there a way around us? Can I do what I am doing in the template in the ajax success callback?

Is there a better way altogether?

Comment: are you using routing ?, if so you can use the resolve property on the route which will make sure the dependencies are loading before the controller code gets executed see http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: Initialize the $scope.user as a new empty JavaScript object, alternate approach is leaving it to AngularJS, it will update the view when the ng-if directive's expression changes (true or false) check my sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet demonstrates when data arrives asynchronously Angular will update the view through its data binding to show the html elements using the `ng-if` directive. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qY3VM2VjyKgocTpNGIoJ?p=preview) e.g. using the `ng-include` directive

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

DefaultController.$inject = ['$timeout'];


function DefaultController($timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.user = {};

  $timeout(function() {
    vm.user.role = 'admin';
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as vm">
    <div ng-if="vm.user.role === 'admin'">
      <span>Hello, Admin</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```